# How to give alert message after successful download of excel file in Java servlet?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, servlets, alert

I want to show alert message after the successful download of excel file. My program downloads the file successfully but it doesn't show the alert message.

I have added the section of java servlet code below which creates and downloads excel file. Would you please suggest me what I need to do to give alert message?

```
        response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + excelFileName + "\"");
        .
        .
        .     // excel creating code
        .
        .

            // Write data in the excel
            ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
            workbook.write(out);

            // Close  workbook
            workbook.close();

            // This below code is supposed to be executed to give alert message but it doesn't work
            PrintStream pw = new PrintStream(out, true, "utf-8");
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            pw.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
            pw.println("alert('" + download_success_message + "');");    
            pw.println("history.back();");
            // pw.println("location='jsp/Hus3report.jsp';");
            pw.println("</script>");

            out.flush();
            out.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else {
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        pw.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");
        pw.println("alert('" + no_data_available + "');");
        pw.println("history.back();");
        // pw.println("location='jsp/Hus3report.jsp';");
        pw.println("</script>");
    }
```

Comment: After downloading file ,you can redirect to some page and put `alert` there .

Comment: @Swati   after I use redirect to other servlet, it gives the alert message but it doesn't download the excel file. Any idea how can I have download as well as alert?